# Numbers before parts and chapters in the table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, numbering

When I use `\tableofcontents*` for adding a table of contents, Roman numbers appear before the name of a part (entered by `\part`) and English numbers is appear before chapters (entered by `\chapter`). How can I change the numbering format? For example, how can I use English numbers instead of Roman ones for parts, in the table of contents.

[image]

Comment: Greek numbers and english numbers? Usually i would say that are roman (or rather Roman) numbers along with (indo-) arabic numbers.

Comment: `\renewcommand{\thepart}{\arabic{part}`

Comment: There is an `}` missing at the end of my previous comment, sorry!

Comment: Numbers will brexit?

Comment: There's no improvement of this post yet :-(

Comment: @ChristianHupfer what do you mean by an improvement?

Comment: @iranano: Providing compilable code of course. A screen shot is not really helpful, in most cases!

Comment: @ChristianHupfer The code is really long. btw, your answer seem working. But I want to change the numbers only in table of contents and not anywhere else.

Comment: @iranano: Well, I don't want to make an answer out of guess work -- if I post a possible solution there will be complains about this and that -- that's the usual experience. Provide the shortest compilable version of your document and we'll see, but in principle, I don't recommend having a different numbering scheme in ToC and in the document body! This is confusing!

Comment: @iranano a minimale example: `\documentclass{Myclass} \usepackage{my package that  haverelation with TOC} \commands{that haverelation with TOC} \begin{document} bla bla \end{document}`

Answer (score 2):

The class `memoir` uses `\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\partnumberline{\thepart}...}` -- redefining `\thepart` will change the numbering of parts throughout the document.

If only the way of `\thepart` is used in the `ToC`, `\thepart` must be redefined within a group that contains `\addcontentsline`, as is done in the patch!

`hyperref` must be loaded after the patch!

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
  \xpatchcmd{\@part}{%
    \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\protect\partnumberline{\thepart}\f@rtoc}%
  }{%
    \begingroup
    \let\@Roman\@arabic%
    \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\protect\partnumberline{\thepart}\f@rtoc}%
    \endgroup
}{}{}
\makeatother

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents*
\part{First part}
\chapter{First chapter}
\chapter{Second chapter}
\part{Second part}
\chapter{First chapter}
\chapter{Second chapter}

\end{document}
```

[image]